# Throwing exception error

Tags: java

My program is not compiling and showing me this error:

```
System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
try {
    int num = scanner.nextInt();
    if (num != 0) {
        throw new Exception("Not zero");
    }
    System.out.println("I'm happy with the input.");
} catch (InputMismatchException e) //InputMismatchException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

{
    System.out.println("Invalid Entry"); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: "+ e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It compiles for me. Also, what you posted is not an error.

Comment: Post the exact and complete error message from the compiler.

Comment: Did you import everything?

Comment: @JBNizet Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - exception javaapplication9.InputMismatchException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement
 at javaapplication9.JavaApplication9.main(JavaApplication9.java:21)

Comment: @skiwi I just imported java.util.Scanner;

Comment: Why do you have a custom `InputMismatchException`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Its not compiling for me rather showing the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

> InputMismatchException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

You're trying to catch an exception which is guaranteed not to be thrown from the try block. This is useless, and even invalid. Remove the `catch (InputMismatchException e)` block.

Actually, the try block can throw a `java.util.InputMismatchException`. So I guess that you're in fact catching an InputMismatchException of another package. Check your imports, and make sure you import `java.util.InputMismatchException` and not some other `com.foo.bar.InputMismatchException`.

EDIT:

the error message confirms what I thought. You're catching `javaapplication9.InputMismatchException`, instead of `java.util.InputMismatchException`. I'm not sure why you defined your own InputMismatchException.